# limit requests on x509 certificate in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, x509certificate, x509

I have made self signed certificates for a website that I'm making. I need to limit a certificate to have only 1 register and 1 vote.

This is my WebSecurityConfig

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final VoterService voterService;

    public WebSecurityConfig(CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, VoterService voterService) {
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.voterService = voterService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register","/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .x509()
                .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)")
                .userDetailsService(this.voterService)
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .failureUrl("/login?error=BadCredentials")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/election", true)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access_denied");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsService() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                if (username.equals("Bob")) {
                    return new User(username, "",
                            AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
                }
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found!");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

With this I can register as many accounts as I want and vote from every account, which isn't the goal. Is there a way to limit this in here or do I have to somehow keep a track of every certificate to every user and check before registering/voting

I didn't try the `or do I have to somehow keep a track of every certificate to every user and check before registering/voting`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are looking for a way to limit people from making more than one account. The certificate and voting are just following from that and don't really matter to the question. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to limit people from making more than one account from one certificate

Comment: Well, if the certificate is what needs to be unique, have a unique constraint on its id in your `user` entity.

Comment: yes and that's with mapping an user with the certificate, I was hoping for a way to do it in this class